# Download source url in Android

Tags: java, android, url, download

I try to save page's source to string.
My code:

```
    public static String saveSource(String link) throws IOException {
    String source = "";
    URL akt = new URL(link);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(akt.openStream(), "utf-8"));
    String linia;
    while ((linia = in.readLine()) != null) {
        source += linia + "\n";
    }
    in.close();
    return source;
}
```

Debbuger told me that problem is here:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(akt.openStream(), "utf-8"));
```

More precisely:

```
akt.openStream()
```

I added to `AndroidManifest.xml`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

**EDIT:**

I check this code in JAVA(intelliJ) and there everything is good...

Comment: What type of problem is the debugger explaining?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem. I must use new `Thread`. Otherside app is crash.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
URL url = new URL(link);     
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(inputStream);
```

And continue from there with your code. You probably need to add some exception handling as well.

Comment: hm, `BufferedReader` need `java.io.Reader`. `inputStream` is `java.io.InputStream`

Comment: I guess you can tweak this a bit. I haven't tried to compile it, but I think you can continue from this point.

Comment: ok, I changed this, but after that I notice that my app crashed in this line
 `InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();`